# How to print serial number to Crystal Reports - WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I have a WPF application, where I print labels for products. Sometimes, I have to print more than one copy of the same label. But the serial number will be different for each copy. I have a database table which keeps track of the last serial number printed. How can I do this using a formula?

Currently I am using the formula as below:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
numbervar slno = ToNumber ({CustomerApp_TblBagLabel.TransactionNo});
slno := slno + 1;
```

Comment: Could you add some example data/formats that you want returned?

Comment: Are you expecting Crystal Reports to update the database field that tracks the transaction number?  If so, it won't do that.

Comment: @craig : I am not updating the database field from crystal report. I will do that in my C# code once the user specify the number of copies. what I need to do is get the last serial number from the database table, increment it by one, and show it in the report each time it prints a label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal Reports will not update a database (by design).

In your situation, I suggest the following approach (pseudo code):

```
begin transaction;

retrieve and increment transaction #;

open report;

pass transaction # to report (via a parameter would be easiest);

print report;

if report prints successfully then
  commit;
else
 rollback;
end if
```

Comment: i am not that expert in crystal reports, is this to be done in the formula?

Comment: no, this would be done in your c# application.

Comment: thanks craig, thats a good approach... just one doubt, how will you send parameter from C# and receive it in CR?

Comment: I suggest that you add a parameter to Crystal Reports, then set it in your C# application.  The parameter can be displayed on the report itself or used to filter a query.